# Unable to scoop out desired portion of address out of long ones

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape addresses out of some html elements using BeautifulSoup library. My intention is to grab the addresses up to the last `County`. The problem I'm facing here is that there are two `County` in all the addresses, so I can't make my script work.

The sources of the three addresses:

```
<div class="col_biz bizgrid_hdr_address">
<strong>Business Address:</strong><br>
650 County Road 375<br><a title="YOUnity Clothing located in Jarrell, TX " href="/tx/williamson/jarrell">Jarrell</a>, <a title="YOUnity Clothing located in TX " href="/tx">TX</a> 76537<br><a title="YOUnity Clothing located in Williamson County, TX " href="/tx/williamson">Williamson County</a><br><br><div class="bizbtn"><a title="YOUnity Clothing" href="http://www.younityclothing.com" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">YOUnity Clothing Website</a></div>
</div>


<div class="col_biz bizgrid_hdr_address">
<strong>Business Address:</strong><br>
39829 County Road 452<br><a title="Eco Sciences, LLC located in Leesburg, FL " href="/fl/lake/leesburg">Leesburg</a>, <a title="Eco Sciences, LLC located in FL " href="/fl">FL</a> 32788<br><a title="Eco Sciences, LLC located in Lake County, FL " href="/fl/lake">Lake County</a><br><br><div class="bizbtn"><a title="Eco Sciences, LLC" href="http://www.ecosciencesllc.com/" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">Eco Sciences, LLC Website</a></div>
</div>


<div class="col_biz bizgrid_hdr_address">
<strong>Business Address:</strong><br>
28 County Road 884<br><a title="R&amp;P Painting located in Rainsville, AL " href="/al/dekalb/rainsville">Rainsville</a>, <a title="R&amp;P Painting located in AL " href="/al">AL</a> 35986<br><a title="R&amp;P Painting located in DeKalb County, AL " href="/al/dekalb">DeKalb County</a>
</div>
```

This is how they are in there:

```
['', 'Business Address:', '39829 County Road 452', 'Leesburg', ',', 'FL', '32788', 'Lake County', 'Eco Sciences, LLC Website', '']

['', 'Business Address:', '28 County Road 884', 'Rainsville', ',', 'AL', '35986', 'DeKalb County', '']

['', 'Business Address:', '650 County Road 375', 'Jarrell', ',', 'TX', '76537', 'Williamson County', 'YOUnity Clothing Website', '']
```

Expected output:

```
Business Address: 39829 County Road 452 Leesburg , FL 32788
Business Address: 28 County Road 884 Rainsville , AL 35986
Business Address: 650 County Road 375 Jarrell , TX 76537
```

I've tried so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class="col_biz bizgrid_hdr_address">
<strong>Business Address:</strong><br>
39829 County Road 452<br><a title="Eco Sciences, LLC located in Leesburg, FL " href="/fl/lake/leesburg">Leesburg</a>, <a title="Eco Sciences, LLC located in FL " href="/fl">FL</a> 32788<br><a title="Eco Sciences, LLC located in Lake County, FL " href="/fl/lake">Lake County</a><br><br><div class="bizbtn"><a title="Eco Sciences, LLC" href="http://www.ecosciencesllc.com/" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">Eco Sciences, LLC Website</a></div>
</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
address = []
for i in soup.select_one(".bizgrid_hdr_address"):
    if not i.string:continue
    if 'County' in i.string.strip():break
    address.append(i.string.strip())
print(' '.join(address).strip())
```

Unfortunately the above attempt produces only `Business Address:` because it encounter the first `County` and breaks the loop whereas my goal here is to grab up to the last `County`.

> How can I capture the desired portion of address?

Comment: Try `soup.select_one(".bizgrid_hdr_address").text.replace('\n', '')`

Comment: Either you didn't read the description or failed to understand what I'm after @JaSON. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't checked the code, but trying to give an idea to use some sort of flag. First encounter will change flag to 1. And second encounter will break from the loop.

```
...
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
address = []

flag = 0
for i in soup.select_one(".bizgrid_hdr_address"):
    if not i.string:continue
    if 'County' in i.string.strip() and flag:
        break
    if 'County' in i.string.strip(): 
        flag = 1
    address.append(i.string.strip())
print(' '.join(address).strip())
```

Comment: What if there is a single `County` located nearest to the end in the long address. I still wish to get the address up to that `County`.

Comment: You don't need that semi-colon in `flag = 0;` Also, in Python it's good to indent `continue` and `break`

Comment: @MITHU are there cases with 1, 2 or more `Country`?

Answer (score 1):

```
b = "2356"
for x in soup.select(".col_biz"):
    x = [i.strip() for i in list(x.strings)]
    goal = [x[int(c)] for c in b]
    print(*goal)
```

Output:

```
650 County Road 375 Jarrell TX 76537
39829 County Road 452 Leesburg FL 32788
28 County Road 884 Rainsville AL 35986
```

Or

```
goal = [(x.contents[3].strip(), x.contents[5]['title'].split("in ")[-1].strip())
        for x in soup.select(".col_biz")]
```

Output:

```
[('650 County Road 375', 'Jarrell, TX'), ('39829 County Road 452', 'Leesburg, FL'), ('28 County Road 884', 'Rainsville, AL')]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that's gonna work for a larger part of the HTML, but there's the word `Website` in every anchor, so you can filter by that.

For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<div class="col_biz bizgrid_hdr_address">
<strong>Business Address:</strong><br>
650 County Road 375<br><a title="YOUnity Clothing located in Jarrell, TX " href="/tx/williamson/jarrell">Jarrell</a>, <a title="YOUnity Clothing located in TX " href="/tx">TX</a> 76537<br><a title="YOUnity Clothing located in Williamson County, TX " href="/tx/williamson">Williamson County</a><br><br><div class="bizbtn"><a title="YOUnity Clothing" href="http://www.younityclothing.com" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">YOUnity Clothing Website</a></div>
</div>


<div class="col_biz bizgrid_hdr_address">
<strong>Business Address:</strong><br>
39829 County Road 452<br><a title="Eco Sciences, LLC located in Leesburg, FL " href="/fl/lake/leesburg">Leesburg</a>, <a title="Eco Sciences, LLC located in FL " href="/fl">FL</a> 32788<br><a title="Eco Sciences, LLC located in Lake County, FL " href="/fl/lake">Lake County</a><br><br><div class="bizbtn"><a title="Eco Sciences, LLC" href="http://www.ecosciencesllc.com/" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">Eco Sciences, LLC Website</a></div>
</div>


<div class="col_biz bizgrid_hdr_address">
<strong>Business Address:</strong><br>
28 County Road 884<br><a title="R&amp;P Painting located in Rainsville, AL " href="/al/dekalb/rainsville">Rainsville</a>, <a title="R&amp;P Painting located in AL " href="/al">AL</a> 35986<br><a title="R&amp;P Painting located in DeKalb County, AL " href="/al/dekalb">DeKalb County</a>
</div>
"""
output = []
for div in BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml").select(".bizgrid_hdr_address"):
    for item in div:
        if item.string and item.string.strip():
            text = item.string.strip()
            if "Website" in text:
                continue
            output.append(text)

addresses = [output[i:i+7] for i in range(0, len(output), 7)]
for address in addresses:
    print(" ".join(address).replace(" ,", ","))
```

This gets you:

```
Business Address: 650 County Road 375 Jarrell, TX 76537 Williamson County
Business Address: 39829 County Road 452 Leesburg, FL 32788 Lake County
Business Address: 28 County Road 884 Rainsville, AL 35986 DeKalb County
```